# How to expose port 8000 to remote access using HttpServer class?

Tags: java, httpserver

I made this tiny api to provide some json on a legacy system. I cannot add Spring or any library to it and thought this would be a simple way. Although it works locally using `curl localhost:8000/jms/health`, when I try it remotely the connection is refused. Running `netstat` returned me this:

```
[userName@machineIp ~]$ sudo netstat -nlpt | grep 8000
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8000              0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      25638/java
```

And this is the class:

```
package somePackage;

import com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpServer;

import org.slf4j.Logger;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.InetSocketAddress;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;

public class HealthHttp {

    public static void init(Logger log) throws IOException {
        HttpServer server = HttpServer.create(new InetSocketAddress("localhost", 8000), 0);
        server.createContext("/jms/health", http -> {

            String body = "{\"hello\":\"world\"}"; // any valid json

            byte[] bytes = body.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);

            http.getResponseHeaders().set("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=" + StandardCharsets.UTF_8);

            http.sendResponseHeaders(200, bytes.length);
            OutputStream output = http.getResponseBody();
            output.write(bytes);
            output.flush();
            output.close();
        });
        server.setExecutor(Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1));
        server.start();
        log.info("Http health server initialized");
    }
}
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Are you able to reach your host computer (the one running the Java program) with `ping`? How about using another server such as a web or database server on that same host? Asking because it seems more like a network issue than an application problem.

Comment: yes, I successfully pinged the remote computer from my local one

Comment: Are you able to run Python on that server? That might be a good test. `python -m SimpleHTTPServer` or `python3 -m http.server` should allow you to access that host over port 8000 and see the file system in the current directory. For details see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Common_questions/set_up_a_local_testing_server. Curious to know if that would work. If not, this is a network configuration issue and opening that port will be specific to your setup. But if you are able to get that to work, I'm at a loss.

Comment: You told the server to listen on 'localhost', address 127.0.0.1, which _by definition_ only works within a host, not for connections from (or to) any other host. To accept connections from another host, either use an address assigned to your network interface (which varies) or easier **use `0.0.0.0`** which by definition means _any_ address(es). (In sockets it's named INADDR_ANY.) Note this may not be sufficient if there are firewall(s); in the 21st century being able to `ping` does NOT guarantee you can connect, or vice versa.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested at the question's comments, changing `localhost` to `0.0.0.0` allowed connections from all external addresses and the loopback

Comment: To allow connections on /all/ external addresses and the loopback.  If you just want connections to be accepted on a specific address, you need to bind to that specific address.